# How can I save a Form so that Main Form can use it?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a main form that has buttons in order to go to the other forms that are mainly complements of this one (pretty much like a database, but without using Access or other software like it).

And what I want to do is basically save all the information on the txtbox´s I have on the other form to be able to manage it within that form and after I had done everything with it, save everything with the Main Form (code already done through Import-Export).

To be more clear imagine a store where you have a form for Clients and other for Products and another Main where this 2 merge and where you save the all information on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going on the assumption hat you are referring to data the entire time. What you  can do is pass the data from the two forms back to the main for using global variables such as

```
public static string ="test";
```

another option is to pass the information directly to the main form gui using delegates. This is exlaine in this other thread if required. [when & why to use delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019402/when-why-to-use-delegates)

Comment: the problem is that I got a system that has to have a next and before buttons, so I can return to my 1st filled form (saved) and my 2nd filled form (saved) also and run both.  Pretty much like a calendar where you have all your appointments and you can "scroll" to them (button next, and before)