# Not getting when to implement delegates and to write a method

Tags: c#

I have an understanding of delegate concept, but not getting the scenarios of when to implement delegate and to write a method. Please anyone help me on this.

Comment: Please, share what have you tried so far?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I don't t think this is a question of HOW to do it, but WHEN.

Comment: follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919882/6797509

Comment: We *execute* methods, e.g. `double x = Math.Sin(0.1233); /* compute sin for me*/` and *pass* delegates: `MyList.Sort(myDelegate); /* sort list using my custom comparsion rule - myDelegate*/`

Comment: Thanks @HamedMoghadasi...the suggested article will help me to get the anwser.