# Assign a new object that calls a method first, in one line

Tags: c#

I have some code like this:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
someObject.Initialize();
this.Object = someObject;
```

I would (rather lazily) like to write it in one line, perhaps like this:

```
this.Object = new SomeObject() { Initialize(); };
```

Is this currently possible or perhaps planned for C# 6.0? Or is this just a really bad and lazy idea?

Comment: FYI c# 5.0 is released already in.Net4.5 with VS2012

Comment: This is certainly not possible in the current C# (5.0). Only properties can be initialized like that (called object initialization). I don't believe it's possible in the next planned version either.

Comment: Oops! I meant 6.0 then. Thanks @SriramSakthivel

Comment: You'd need a strong motivation to add a 'syntactic sugar' feature of that kind to a language. I can't see the need in this case, to be honest. The current syntax is already simple, clear and effective...

Comment: How about putting `Initialize()` inside a constructor?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev I can't believe I didn't think of that! You should convert that into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not directly possible but you can create a little helper:

```
public class Helper<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T Init(Action<T> body)
    {
        T obj = new T();
        body(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
this.Object = Helper<SomeClass>.Init(obj => obj.Initialize());
```

or more complicated cases:

```
this.Object = Helper<SomeClass>.Init(obj => {
    obj.Initialize();
    obj.SomeOtherMethod();
    ...
});
```

Comment: +1 I certainly wouldn't have had figured out how to do that on my own. Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
this.object = (new SomeOjbect()).Initialize();
```

but you must edit the initialize() method by adding "return this"

Comment: True. but I find this way much more readable and easier to understand what's going on. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You could have tried it, and you would find out that this is currently not possible. And in my opinion it is absolutely not needed and would reduce readability. You can do plenty of other things like putting it the method in your constructor.

You can't say `this.Object = new SomeObject().Initialize();`, like the one of the answers specifies, unless the Initialize method returns SomeObject.

Comment: I already tried it, and couldn't find any way to do it, hence my question that aims to ask if it's possible to do it another way.

Comment: Like I said it is not possible, but what stops you from putting the method in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, putting it into the constructor would probably be the best approach, as someone already suggested in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468029/assign-a-new-object-that-calls-a-method-first-in-one-line#comment35979269_23468029), and I'm an idiot (no sarcasm intended) for not thinking of that.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments, it is possible to use methods in a class constructor:

```
public class SomeObject 
{
    public SomeObject() 
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    public void Initialize() 
    {
        //do initialization stuff
    }
}
```

However, you should not call virtual methods from within a constructor.

**More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place the Intialize() method in the constructor, but if that's not what you are looking for then you can do the following:

```
(this.Object = new SomeObject()).Initialize();
```

Works fine:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QmSBzL